# not valid JSON python-instagram

Tags: python, json, instagram-api

I just can't start using instagram api.

The code from github https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "***"
client_secret = "***"
scope = 'public_content'
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id = "***", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print("hey")
```

Errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File ...Python35-32\lib\site-packages\simplejson\decoder.py", line
>   400, in raw_decode
>       return self.scan_once(s, idx=_w(s, idx).end()) simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1
>   (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\PolyProgrammist\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\instagram\bind.py",
>   line 131, in _do_api_request
>       raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
>   instagram.bind.InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response,
>   not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this has something to do with recent enforcement of permission reviews (which I think changes authentication) that Instagram laid down on June 1st.
https://www.instagram.com/developer/changelog/

Given that the python-instagram library hasn't been updated since [march](https://github.com/facebookarchive/python-instagram/commit/6522cffe19065d456ceb0d10b0cd1a13c5026380), it is probably out of date and not handling authentication errors correctly.

My guess is that the instagram API is returning a JSON formatted errors, which is causing `simplejson` to throw that exception.

Comment: so what should i do? i want just use inst api(get subscriptions list or like some post) how can i do it